# Can a scroll compressor be used to generate power?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, turbines, compressors

[Scroll compressors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_compressor) are efficient, reliable, and a fill a pressure/flow niche in the array of available compressor technologies. However, I have never seen one used the other direction for generating power from a compressed air source, steam, or power cycle. Any thoughts on why this might be the case? Any examples of one being used as a prime mover?

Comment: There seems to be a research paper in that direction, "Powered Reverse Running of Scroll Compressors" from Hugenroth and Barito, 1998: https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/icec/1285/

Comment: @OpticalResonator, Thanks! That helped me find the "scroll expander" vocab I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like "scroll expander" was the term I was looking for.

Still looks to be a pretty rare application, but here are some instances:

1. [Air Squared commercially available scroll expander](https://airsquared.com/products/scroll-expanders/e15h022a-sh/)
2. Here is a good [thesis from Oregon State University](https://atami.oregonstate.edu/biblio/development-small-scale-scroll-expander) ([direct pdf link](https://ir.library.oregonstate.edu/downloads/v405sd97c?locale=en)).
3. Some short [Science Direct Excerpts](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/scroll-expander)